# Control DataBindings doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, 2-way-object-databinding, ef-core-6.0

I have Dto like this

```
public partial class DepartmentDto
{
public int IdDepartment { get; set; }
public string NameDepartment { get; set; }
public string DescriptionDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this method to binding controls

```
 private DepartmentDto departmentDto = new();
 private void BindingControls()
{
    txtID.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", departmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.IdDepartment), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    txtTitle.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", departmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.NameDepartment), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
    txtDescription.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", departmentDto, nameof(departmentDto.DescriptionDepartment), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
}
```

When I change the value of any text boxes the **departmentDto** get it's values whiteout any problems.
But When I change **departmentDto** on gridview double click event like this

```
 private void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    departmentDto = listDepartmentDto.Current as DepartmentDto;
}
```

The **departmentDto** get it's value but the text boxes doesn't reflect this changes
Is there **automatic** way to do it or do I need to fill it out like this

```
     txtID.EditValue = departmentDto.IdDepartment;
     txtTitle.EditValue = departmentDto.NameDepartment;
     txtDescription.EditValue = departmentDto.DescriptionDepartment;
```

Comment: If the DataBinding is set correctly, this: `departmentDto = listDepartmentDto.Current as DepartmentDto;` is counter productive. -- Why do you have a single object assigned as the source of the Binding? It appears you have a List of those objects elsewhere. Use a BindingSource as mediator, so you also don't need to reset the binding each time the actual `Current` reference changes.

Comment: Yes you are right I have BindingSource listDepartmentDto it's attached to grid control data source
But it seems odd that the user sees the changes in the grid view without committing them to the database

Comment: Committing the changes to a database is a different matter. If you want your Controls to reflect the values of the currently selected object in the List (while the Grid moves the current Row), use the same BindingSource as the source of the Bindings.